# How can you print 1 to 10 & 10 to 1 by using recursion with single variable

Tags: recursion

I am preparing for my interview tomorrow -- I need the answer to this question:

How can you print 1 to 10 & 10 to 1 by using recursion with single variable

Comment: If you can't figure it out yourself, asking it here is cheating on the interview.

Comment: Is this interview for a programming job?

Comment: @Lerxst: What else could it be?

Comment: If it's an interview for an architecture job this question is unlikely to come up

Comment: +1 hehe @Michael, yeah not a bad idea!

Comment: @SLaks thats kind of the point... :)

Comment: if you are trying to make a single function that can print 1,2,3..,9,10,9,8,...,2,1.. I don't think its possible with a single variable.. you would need 2 to know which direction you are coming from and hence what value you need to print next

Comment: @adi92, nobody mentioned a single function :-)

Comment: @adi92 it is definitely possible with one function using symmetry. see mine and phong's answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to get downvoted I just know it but here is (a) solution.  Not the best one but you should be able to make it better yourself.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        printNumDown(10);
    }

    static void printNumDown(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
        if (num > 1)
            printNumDown(num - 1);
        else
            printNumUp(num + 1);
    }

    static void printNumUp(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
        if (num < 10)
            printNumUp(num + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need the answer to this question". Not "I need help with this" but very specifically "I need the answer". So you shouldn't be downvoted in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

```
void print_recursive(int n) { 
    printf("%d\n", n);
    if (n < 10)
        print_recursive(n+1);
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

With **one function** and **one variable** only:

```
void recurs(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    if (num < 10) {
        recurs(num + 1);
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
}

int main() {
    recurs(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm completely blind, this doesn't count down again.

Comment: Note that he has printf() twice. It is using the symmetry of counting up and down again so only needs to loop 1 - 10;

Comment: @Alastair You could just try running it. The concept does work, although he used `%n` instead of `%d` and forgot the newline; Jerry [got it right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879496/how-can-you-print-1-to-10-10-to-1-by-using-recursion-with-single-variable/2879619#2879619)

Comment: Ooooo, I see now. Very nice. My apologies for the lack of faith :)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for noticing the problem in the printf. It is now corrected.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to figure this out yourself.

*Hint*: Make a method that takes a `10` as a parameter, then prints the parameter and calls itself with `9`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sneaky way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void recur_up (int n) {
    if (n > 1)
        recur_up (n - 1);
    printf ("%d\n", n);
}

static void recur_down (int n) {
    printf ("%d\n", n);
    if (n > 1)
        recur_down (n - 1);
}

int main (void) {
    recur_up (10);
    recur_down (10);
    return 0;
}
```

which generates:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

---

It would have been a lot more elegant going down then up since you could do that with a single function:

```
static void recur_both (int n) {
    printf ("%d\n", n);
    if (n > 1)
        recur_down (n - 1);
    printf ("%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: well its still possible to do it with a single function

Comment: Why, yes it is, at the cost of hardcoding the upper limit (not _overly_ flexible). But the specs didn't call for a single function, just recursion and a single variable :-)

Answer (score 3):

Javascript version:

```
printNumber(1);

function printNumber(num){
  document.write(num);
  if (num < 10) 
     printNumber(num + 1);
  document.write(num);
}
```

Comment: code golfed: `f(1);function f(x) {d=document;d.write(x);if(x<10)f(x+1);d.write(x);}`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you guys all being so difficult? In Pseudocode:

```
function recurfunc(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
    echo (-1 * (floor(abs(n)) - 10));
        recurfunc(n+1);
    }
}
```

Then call recurfunc with -9.5 as its start.

Seems kind of obvious to me that the answer is using absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in Ruby:

```
puts (r = ->n=1 { if n<=10 then [n] + r.(n+1) + [n] else [] end }).()
```

Note: before you conclude that Ruby is an unreadable mess even worse than Perl, let me assure you: this is *not* idiomatic Ruby. Idiomatic Ruby would be more like

```
def recursive_count_up_and_down(n=1)
  return [] unless n<=10
  [n] +
  recursive_count_up_and_down(n + 1) +
  [n]
end

puts recursive_count_up_and_down
```

Of course, Ruby is an imperative language, so doing it *really* idiomatically would not use recursion:

```
1.upto(10) do |i| puts i end
10.downto(1) do |i| puts i end
```

Here's another neat one that unfortunately doesn't use recursion, either:

```
puts Array.new(20) {|i| if i < 10 then i+1 else 20-i end }
```

BTW: all the solutions so far, including mine, are actually cheating, because technically they use *two* variables, because

```
function foo {}
```

is equivalent to

```
var foo = λ{}
```

So, in my example above, there are *two* variables: `recursive_count_up_and_down` and `n`. We could eliminate both of those by writing in a tacit point-free style (for example in the SK-calculus), but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. (Meaning I can't figure it out :-) )

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void c(int n)
{
   static int i;
   if(i<n)
   {
     i++;
     printf("%d",i);
     c(n);
   }
}
int main()
{
  c(5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintNumberFrom1To10{

```
public static void printNumber(int num){


    if(num<=10){


    System.out.println(num);


    printNumber(num+1);


    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Enter Your Number: ");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



    int num = sc.nextInt();




    printNumber(num);






}
```

}